# Target parent LIs only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target just the LI that are direct children of the "Main" UL. I have seen solutions that use JS or reverse the effects of the parent UL by manipulating the children LI later, but this is not what we are looking for.
(for example, upsizing the text to 1.2em requires us to downsize the text 0.8em or whatever the math is, which is why we need the children to remain unaffected)

```
<ul class="siteMapMain">
   <li>Operations
    <ul class="siteMapSecond">
      <li>Sales Development</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Call Center</li>
   <li>Training
     <ul class="siteMapSecond">
       <li>Work Instruction</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

So in this list, we want to change "Operations", "Call Center", and "Training" to red, but leave the other LI as is. Pure CSS, no JavaScript or similar.

We tried a number of combinations of > + ~ operators and did not get the desired results. We WERE able to target just the children UL's LIs, but we are trying to avoid this "Work Around".

We tried all the solutions in the similar questions, but they are only "Similar", not giving the desired results. What you SHOULD see with the desired results are the top level LIs in red and the others ("Videos", "Links", etc) should be black.

JsFiddle if so desired:
http://jsfiddle.net/billynair/r4h7z84g/

Comment: That's cascading stylesheets for ya, always cascading. I'm afraid you'd need to set at least two rules to handle this, one for the children and one for the grandchildren to override the cascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some properties, like `color`, are [inherited](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherited-property) from parents to children.

Therefore, if you use `color: red` on the `li`, its inner `ul` child will inherit that style too.

You can restore the initial value with the [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial) keyword.

```
ul.siteMapMain > li {
  color: red;
}
ul.siteMapMain > li > * {
  color: initial;
}
```

```css
ul.siteMapMain > li{
  color: red;
}
ul.siteMapMain > li > * {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul class="siteMapMain">
  <li>Operations
    <ul class="siteMapSecond">
      <li>Sales Development</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Call Center</li>
  <li>Training
    <ul class="siteMapSecond">
      <li>Videos</li>
      <li>Links</li>
      <li>Printable</li>
      <li>Work Instruction</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Policy and Procedure</li>
  <li>Documents & Templates</li>
  <li>Links</li>
  <li>Reporting</li>
  <li>Media
    <ul class="siteMapSecond">
      <li>Audio</li>
      <li>Video</li>
      <li>Photo</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `initial` solves the problems we were having! As far as targeting ONLY the parent, it is looking like that is NOT possible, and since countering the effects of the original CSS code was our problem, using `initial`, rather than trying to calculate the difference of what was changed, is the best way to solve this.

Comment: Should be noted that the initial keyword isn't supported in IE at all.

Comment: Good to know! (Another IE note). FORTUNATELY, this is for an internal website, and the company does NOT install IE on anyone's computer and the IT guys will not help anyone one using IE from their personal computers, so we are good (on THIS particular site, anyway)

Comment: @BillyNair This company rocks :) There are too many opposite cases.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two rules, otherwise the styles will be inherited (that's why its called cascading):

```
ul li {
    color: black;
}

ul.siteMapMain > li {
    color:red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://fiddle)

Comment: Yes, cascading is what was happening, but after reading the "Child Combinator" section of this article (css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) I was given hope that selecting only the first set of LI was possible. 2 rules looks like the only answer for now...